# Blackscreen without TTY only on cold boot with KUbuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, drivers, 18.04, nvidia, kubuntu

I'm trying to debug a cold boot-only problem with my laptop where I don't get any logs or screen output.
**Setup:**

```
KUbuntu 18.04.3
KDE Plasma 5.12.9
KDE Framework 5.44.0
i7-6700HQ
GeForce GTX 965M
```

So hybrid intelHD gpu/nvidia via prime-select and nvidia drivers.

**Problem:**
A cold-boot or restart (and for 90% plugged in HDMI display) will result in the following:

- Post
- Blackscreen (laptop & external screen)
- No TTY (Ctrl-Alt-F2 ..)

If I then press Ctrl-Alt-Del long enough (or Ctr-Alt-Print-B), the system reboots and everything works fine. It doesn't matter whether I selected intel or nvidia in prime-select.

I don't have any journalctl logs for the failed boot, only for previous successful startups.

**(possible) Questions:**
How could I try to debug this ? Are there any known problems ? Or am I simply using a buggy, old driver/kernel/.. ?
Of course I could *just* install a brand new version and retry, but as I'm using this for work and it still "works" I postponed writing this for over a year.

**logged errors from journalctl**
(On a successfull boot as there are no logs for failed ones.., some of them I see while booting.)

```
kernel: ACPI Error: [_OSI] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PAGD._STA, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
kernel: MODSIGN: Couldn't get UEFI db list
systemd-udevd[414]: Invalid rule /etc/udev/rules.d/90-extraacl.rules:4: unknown key '"KERNEL'
smartd[2429]: Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 8 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors // smart says it's cool
```

Comment: no, this doesn't fix the bootup problems